# how to get transform a local image to a web accessable image

Tags: database, image, imagedownload

Generally,if we want to display a image in the web page,we give the uri of the image resource like: http://host:port/image/xxx.jpg.

Now,there are some images in my file system,and I save its absolute path in the db.

Like this;

```
id     name     address   image
1      xxxx     xxxx      C:/images/xxx.jpg
```

Now if the entity is retrived,its image should be displayed in the page.

How to make it?

What I thought is copy the image under the web server dir,then build its url,then the page can render it. But I wonder if this is a good idea? Is there any other way?

Comment: What kind of programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a webpage or a httphandler which retrieves the requested image from the database then send it to the user using httpresponse and the correct mimetype. Using the querystring the image is identified like:

- http://domain/image.aspx?id=123
- http://domain/image.ashx?id=123

Unfortunately you didn't specify the programming language you are using. If its .Net I could create some example code.

Comment: I wonder if "http://domain/image.ashx?id=123" can be within the img tag? like <img src="http://domain/image.ashx?id=123" />??

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a try.